# logging all queries after execution in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i want to log all queries after execution using hooks.
-i enabled hooks in config.php
-this is my hook-->

```
 $hook['post_controller'] = array(    
    'class' => 'Db_log',             
    'function' => 'logQueries',     
   'filename' => 'db_log.php',    
   'filepath' => 'hooks'         
  );
```

-and this is hook defination-->

```
class Db_log 
{

    function __construct() 
    {
    }


    function logQueries() 
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();

        $filepath = APPPATH . 'logs/Query-log-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.php'; 
        $handle = fopen($filepath, "a+");                        

        $times = $CI->db->query_times;
        foreach ($CI->db->queries as $key => $query) 
        { 
            $sql = $query . " \n Execution Time:" . $times[$key]; 

            fwrite($handle, $sql . "\n\n");    
        }

        fclose($handle);  
    }

}
```

--its creating query_log file
--but no records of queries being stored

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your Code looks fine - the only reason why this doesn't work is in your DB Configuration - take a look @your DB Connection in the database.php under application/config/

There is an option "save_queries" which should be set to true

```
$db['default'] = array(
    ...
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: above code is now working fine...but its logging SELECT queries only,what if i want only INSERT,UPDATE and DELETE be logged instead of SELECT queries?

Comment: even the other types of Queries should get logged - in the queries are all type of queries

Comment: is there any option to "$CI->db->queries"

Comment: what do you mean with option ? do you want to separate inserts, updates, delets and selects from each other ?

Comment: no offense man but this is a pretty simple task to achieve, just adapt some logic into your foreach loop and thats it - just write it - if you need assistance show what you've done so far and I'm certainly willing to help -but I'm not gonna write an entire code for you ;)

Comment: internal redirection in application was causing it to overtake hook execution, that's why it wasn't logging modification statements...i found the solution thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

For me it only worked when I define de $hook array in config/hooks.php .