# How to logging all queries after execution in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have try to insert all codeigniter queries after execute the mysql query. Unable to insert all query anyone can help me resolve this issue

Comment: which code have you tried ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [logging all queries after execution in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587940/logging-all-queries-after-execution-in-codeigniter)

Comment: this is not an appropriate way of asking question. and what code have you done so for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for logging specific query in log file:

Create a `logFile.log` file then write your query in this file.

```
$sql_query = "insert into tablename (column1, column2) values(value1, value2)";
file_put_contents('logFile.log', json_encode($sql_query , true), FILE_APPEND);
```

Hope this will help you a bit.

Or you can follow the duplication question here: [logging all queries after execution in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587940/logging-all-queries-after-execution-in-codeigniter)